# Cannot wake up RigidBody after gravity change

Tags: rust, bevy, rapier, rapier-3d

I have a cube that is supposed to be floating (gravity set to 0). After an event, the cube is supposed to "fall down" (gravity set to 1). I know that the RigidBody is asleep when gravity is set to `0`, so I am trying to wake it up by applying an `ExternalForce`.

Here is my code

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;
use std::time::Duration;
use bevy_inspector_egui::quick::WorldInspectorPlugin;
use bevy_rapier3d::prelude::*;
use leafwing_input_manager::prelude::*;
use prelude::*;

#[derive(Component)]
struct MyGameCamera;

#[derive(Reflect, Component, Default)]
#[reflect(Component)]
struct ActiveElement {
    pendulum_timer: Timer,
    pendulum_inverted: bool,
}

#[derive(Component)]
struct Player;

#[derive(Actionlike, PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy, Hash, Debug)]
enum Action {
    Drop,
}

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .register_type::<ActiveElement>()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_plugin(RapierPhysicsPlugin::<NoUserData>::default())
        .add_plugin(RapierDebugRenderPlugin::default())
        .add_plugin(WorldInspectorPlugin::default())
        .add_plugin(InputManagerPlugin::<Action>::default())
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .add_system(drop)
        .run()
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
) {
    // Camera
    commands.spawn((
        Camera3dBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(-2.0, 2.5, 5.0).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
            ..Default::default()
        },
        MyGameCamera,
    ));
    // Light
    commands.spawn(PointLightBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(4.0, 10.0, 4.0),
        point_light: PointLight {
            intensity: 3000.0,
            shadows_enabled: true,
            range: 30.0,
            ..default()
        },
        ..default()
    });
    // Floor
    commands
        .spawn(PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshes.add(shape::Plane::from_size(5.0).into()),
            material: materials.add(Color::rgb(0.3, 0.5, 0.3).into()),
            ..default()
        })
        .insert(Collider::cuboid(100.0, 0.1, 100.0));
    // cube
    commands
        .spawn(PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshes.add(Mesh::from(shape::Box::new(1.0, 0.2, 1.0))),
            material: materials.add(Color::rgb(0.8, 0.7, 0.6).into()),
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 1.6, 0.0),
            ..default()
        })
        .insert(RigidBody::Dynamic)
        .insert(Collider::cuboid(0.5, 0.1, 0.5))
        .insert(ColliderMassProperties::Density(1.0))
        .insert(Restitution::coefficient(0.1))
        .insert(Name::new("Cube"))
        .insert(GravityScale(0.0))
        .insert(ActiveElement {
            pendulum_timer: Timer::new(Duration::from_secs(3), TimerMode::Repeating),
            pendulum_inverted: false,
        });

    // Input
    commands
        .spawn(InputManagerBundle::<Action> {
            action_state: ActionState::default(),
            input_map: InputMap::new([(KeyCode::Space, Action::Drop)]),
        })
        .insert(Player);
}


fn drop(
    action: Query<&ActionState<Action>, With<Player>>,
    mut query: Query<(&mut GravityScale, &mut ExternalForce, &mut Sleeping), With<ActiveElement>>,
) {
    let action_state = action.single();
    if action_state.just_pressed(Action::Drop) {
        query.iter_mut().for_each(|(mut gravity_scale, mut external_force, mut sleeping)| {
            gravity_scale.0 = 1.0;
            sleeping.sleeping = false;
            external_force.force = Vec3::new(200.0, 30000.0, 0.0);
            external_force.torque = Vec3::new(10.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        });
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[...]
[dependencies]
bevy = "0.10.0"
bevy_rapier3d = { version = "0.21.0", features = [ "simd-stable", "debug-render", "parallel" ] }
leafwing-input-manager = "0.9.0"
bevy-inspector-egui = "0.18.0"
[...]
```

I can see with the egui inspector that the gravity is applied to the `Cube`, but the RigidBody is not woken up (I assume...). What am I missing?

Comment: Your query does not return anything, therefore the code within the `for_each` closure is never executed.

Comment: indeed  removing the `Sleeping` component and adding an `ExternalForce` component to the spawn command solved the issue. Thanks!